# Author rejected edit "actively harms readability"?

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

I made [this edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18729693) to fix what I thought were non-trivial typos and grammar issues. The author of the answer rejected it with "This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read". I thought that was a bit strange.

I'd like to know if the general SO community agrees with this rejection and whether such grammar edits are truly useful or not.

Comment: If you want to know more that they've already said on why they rejected it then why are you asking us?  Ask them?

Comment: I don't want to pollute that question and answer with non-technical comments. Also, I saw similar questions here (for different edits).

Comment: Discussing how best to word the actual post is an entirely appropriate thing to discuss in the comments of said post.  Asking a bunch of people why someone else did what they did isn't going to tell you anything.  None of us know any more about why that person rejected your edit than you do.  If the reason you were given isn't enough, you'll need to *ask them*.

Comment: I wanted to know the general opinion (if others agree and would've done the same) and more importantly, if the community feels that these kind of edits really are not that useful i.e. the general consensus on usefulness of grammar edits.

Comment: Then why did you ask why the author rejected it, instead of that?

Comment: Fair enough. I reworded my question.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Your edit made things much easier to read by fixing grammar errors the OP made.

My guess is the OP either took it personally or does not understand the grammatical errors they were making.

Personally, I find your edit to be beneficial, but on a side note, if the author rejects the edit, best to just move on and not waste time arguing over grammar.

Comment: As a side note OP is from Germany and English might not be their first language.

Comment: The OP may or may not be located in Germany, but the OP most likely learned English in India, based on the style of English (I can tell after all this time).

Comment: @Peter Mortensen the OP who rejected the edit is Germany the OP of this question is from India yea

Comment: Sorry, I should not have used "OP". I meant user "[pvpkiran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6565093/pvpkiran)" (that may or may not be located in Germany). That user learned English in India (or much less likely influenced therefrom).

Comment: What about his profile makes you think they learned English in India?

Comment: @Peter Mortensen: I'm seeing a little bit of overlap in some linguistic quirks but nothing that suggests heavy Indian English influence either. Having said that, Kiran *is* an Indian given name...